# (UINavigationController) PushViewController fails after PresentViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am building an application in which the main content is a navigation controller. However, the first time the app loads, I am pushing another view controller on top of that controller (the user has to register etc). This has to be separate from the navigation controller so the user cannot just backtrack. Currently, Navigation through my navigation controller works only on times when the other view controller isn't loaded.

The code to load the 'register' VC if it is needed:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([prefs objectForKey:@"id"]) {

}
else {
    RegisterViewController * rvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"registerVC"];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:rvc animated:NO completion:^(void){}];
}
```

On completion of registration:

```
[viewCtrl dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void){
                NSLog(@"VIEW DISMISSED PROPERLY");
            }];
```

Note: viewCtrl is the viewController pushed on. Also On times when the navigationcontroller stops working 'view dismissed properly' is called. So I know that the view is being dismissed.

Finally, code to push another page normally onto the navigation controller:

```
ContactViewController * cvc = [self.view.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactVC"];
[self.view.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:NO];
```

Just to reiterate, ContactViewController only loads if the registration page wasn't loaded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should push other ViewController after dismiss finished:

```
    [viewCtrl dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^(void){
                    NSLog(@"VIEW DISMISSED PROPERLY");
                    ContactViewController * cvc = [self.view.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contactVC"];
                    [self.view.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:NO]
                }];
```